# MYsql select only rows with max value on a column for each record

Tags: mysql, join

I have user location and user table in MySql.

Now what I want is, I want to fetch Full_Name , Mobile_Number,

Latitude, Longitude,  LocationSyncDateTime  for last inserted or

latest record against each Username according to

LocationSyncDateTime.

below i have attached screenshots of my table

[image: User Table]

[image: User Location]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.

Comment: Not workbench, please give version details of MySQL server

Comment: Mysql Version 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get [Maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html) value of `LocationSyncDateTime` for a `User_Name` in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) `t3`.
- Join the main tables to this Derived table on `User_Name` and max value of `LocationSyncDateTime`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT u.Full_Name, 
       u.Mobile_Number, 
       l.Latitude, 
       l.Longitude, 
       l.LocationSyncDateTime 
FROM user AS u 
JOIN location AS l ON l.User_Name = u.User_Name 
JOIN (SELECT l2.User_Name, 
             MAX(l2.LocationSyncDateTime) AS LocationSyncDateTime 
      FROM location AS l2 
      GROUP BY l2.User_Name
     ) AS t3 ON t3.User_Name = l.User_Name 
                AND t3.LocationSyncDateTime = l.LocationSyncDateTime
```

Comment: Will check this one and get back to you.

Comment: @kirangirase happy to help :)